How to run Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components library on NET9
Simple setup: Create a new Blazor Web App with Auto and Per Page/Component solutions. Add a new Razor class library to contain the components, add Microsoft's Fluent UI Blazor Components library. This library is then referenced in the Client project, but the build fails. The output error message says the following:
MSB4018 The "DefineStaticWebAssetEndpoints" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 keySelector, Func2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.Tasks.DefineStaticWebAssetEndpoints.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() BlazorApp9TestUI.Client C:\Users\xxxx.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.webassembly.pack\9.0.0-preview.7.24405.7\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WebAssembly.Browser.targets    347
I tried installing the FluentUI library directly into the Client project, and it worked.
Has anyone else run into the same issue?

A quick review of the project's "dev" branch looks like .NET 9 support is there. Maybe it hasn't reached a published pre-release version yet?

Could you just try adding the library in client project only. Remove any references to Fluent UI from the Razor Class Library (RCL) project.Remove or disable the static web assets from being added in the RCL. make sure that static assets like CSS, JavaScript, or any other resources from the Fluent UI library are included only once in your client project.is it possible for you to share the small repro sample with us.

I'm closing this as I installed a newer version of .NET 9, and the problem disappeared.
